# Extension of Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $f|_k$ is $L$-lipschitz and $f=0$ outside of $K$ and in $f|_{\partial K}$.

> Is $f$ Lipschitz?

My try: if $x,y$ are in $K$ or outside $K$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$.

However is $x\in K$ and $y \notin K$? Taking $x^*$ a point on the segment from $x$ to $y$ that is also in $\partial K$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(x^*)|\leq L|x-x^*|\leq L|x-y|$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks ok, the key is being zero on the boundary, otherwise $f=1_K$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat: Is it that simple? The segment from $x$ to $y$ could contain (uncountably) many points of $\partial K$.

Comment: Well, essentially the fact that it is Lipshitz on $K$ means that it must drop to zero in a 'Lipschitz-like' fashion near the boundary. If $x $ is on the boundary there is nothing to prove, otherwise pick any point on the boundary as an intermediate point.

Comment: $K$ does not have to be connected, but it must still be Lipschitz across any two points of $K$.

Comment: @MartinR What's the problem of having more than one point of $\partial K$ on that segment?

Comment: I was thinking too complicated, your argument seems to be fine (as @copper.hat noted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument it fine. You don't need  that $K$ is compact, only that is is closed (so that $\partial K \subset K$).

In the case $x \in K$, $y \notin K$ I would elaborate on why the segment from $x$ to $y$ contains a point $x^* \in \partial K$, and that is a connectedness argument:

Let $S$ denote that segment from $x$ to $y$. If $S \cap \partial K$ is empty then $x \in K^0$, $y \in K^C$, and
$$
 S = (S \cap K^0) \cup (S \cap K^C)
$$
is a partition of $S$ into disjoint, relative open sets, which are both non-empty. This is not possible because $S$ is connected.